# Java: NULL in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, nullpointerexception

Please I have this question which is a bit theoretical, but I would like to understand it.

Why if I pass a null argument to a constructor do I get a `NullPointerException`?

This is my example

```
new AttendeeDetail("Gus Goose","1151","15-01-2012",(Integer) null,null)
```

This is the class:

```
public class AttendeeDetail {

    private String ticketholder_name;
    private String user_id;
    private String date_of_birth;
    private int tickets_purchased;
    private ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;

    public AttendeeDetail(String ticketholder_name, String user_id, 
        String date_of_birth, int tickets_purchased, ArrayList<Ticket> tickets) 
    {
        this.ticketholder_name=ticketholder_name;
        this.user_id=user_id;
        this.date_of_birth=date_of_birth;
        this.tickets_purchased=tickets_purchased;
        this.tickets=tickets;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do not you try it?

Comment: @KickButtowski I did and got a NullPointerException indeed

Comment: I feel it is good question and +1 already

Comment: Why do you parse null to integer? That is the place where there is a NPE

Comment: @Raghav The op asked valid question and we are trying to learn

Comment: Look at builder pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

an `int` can't be `null`.
If you really need to pass a null value, use the `Integer` type

Answer (score 6):

You're assigning an `Integer`: `(Integer) null` to an `int` parameter: `int tickets_purchased`.

`Integer`, as a reference type can be `null`, but `int` as a primitive type cannot be, so an error occurs during the attempt to convert.

This conversion is called an [unboxing operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: so as I can understand null does not apply to objects ?

Comment: @KickButtowski Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: The problem is not at this point, it happens at the moment the constructor is called, as the constructor has an `int` parameter, not `Integer`.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer wrapped = null;
        int primitive = wrapped;
    }
}
```

Now, let's see what this code compiles to by using `javap`:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: aconst_null
   1: astore_1
   2: aload_1
   3: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
   6: istore_2
   7: return
```

As you can see, in order to unbox the `Integer` it tries to invoke [`Integer#intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--) method on `null` reference, and therefore it throws `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers mention, the problem is this - `(Integer) null`.

When the formal type of a method argument is `int` and you try to pass `(Integer) null`, the following is going to happen.

1. The Java compiler is going to say *"Ah! I have an `Integer` value, and I need to convert it to an `int` value.  I will output code to **unbox** it!"*.
2. The code to unbox the value is a call to `Integer.intValue()`, using the value-to-be-unboxed as the target object.  Except that the value is `null` ... not a real object reference.
3. At runtime, you end up calling `intValue()` on the `null`, and that throws an NPE.

Some compilers will issue a warning for this, saying that the code will always throw an NPE.  However, this is legal Java code, so a conformant Java compiler cannot call this a compilation error.

---

Possible solutions:

1. Don't use `(Integer) null` as the parameter.  Pass an `int` value, or an actual (not null) `Integer` object.  In this case, zero looks like a reasonable substitute.
2. Change the type of the formal parameter from `int` to `Integer` ... and propagate the change to the places where the corresponding field value is returned, used, etcetera.

The first alternative is probably the correct one, unless you *really* need to model the possibility that an "attendee" has purchased an *unknown* number of tickets.  (And if you do need to model that, then your application has to cope with this possibility ... somehow.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you get a null pointer exception because Java will try to autobox your null Integer to an int, and that wont work since null ints are not allowed :) (since you already tried it out i thought id give an explenation why you see this behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

`int tickets_purchased = (Integer)null;` this is not allowed in java.

You can use `Integer tickets_purchased = (Integer)null;`

Comment: either this cannot be an answer or does not answer the op fully