# If a constructors value is null, can I give it a default?

Tags: java, android, constructor

I am using a recycler view to display data on my app. When I want to get the information from an API that I am using I am taking in 14 different variables.

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length();i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

    //object.getJSONObject("test");

    Personnel personnel = new Personnel(

            object.getInt("contactType"),
            object.getString("currentTime"),
            object.getString("clockIn"),
            object.getString("clockOut"),
            object.getInt("isClockedIn"),
            object.getString("clockInPhotoName"),
            object.getDouble("clockInLat"),
            object.getDouble("clockInLng"),
            object.getDouble("clockOutLat"),
            object.getDouble("clockOutLng"),
            object.getDouble("projectSiteLat"),
            object.getDouble("projectSiteLng"),
            object.getDouble("clockInDistanceFromProjectSiteInMetres"),
            object.getDouble("clockOutDistanceFromProjectSiteInMetres")
    );

    personnelList.add(personnel);
}
```

But in my response body from my http call, some times for example, the object that is calling "isClockedIn", may be empty, and if I do this, then my constructor wont make an object.

This is my very long constructor:

```
public Personnel(int contactType, String totalTimeSummary, String clockInTime, String clockOutTime, int isClockedIn, String clockInPhotoName, double clockInLat, double clockInLong, double clockOutLat, double clockOutLong, double projectLat, double projectLong, double clockInDistance, double clockOutDistance) {
    this.contactType = contactType;
    this.totalTimeSummary = totalTimeSummary;
    this.clockInTime = clockInTime;
    this.clockOutTime = clockOutTime;
    this.isClockedIn = isClockedIn;
    this.clockInPhotoName = clockInPhotoName;
    this.clockInLat = clockInLat;
    this.clockInLong = clockInLong;
    this.clockOutLat = clockOutLat;
    this.clockOutLong = clockOutLong;
    this.projectLat = projectLat;
    this.projectLong = projectLong;
    this.clockInDistance = clockInDistance;
    this.clockOutDistance = clockOutDistance;
}
```

I was looking around and saw that you can just make a default constructor if my other constructor doesn't fill all the needed variables, but of course I dont want to do this because then all of the parameters will be empty.

Cheers.

Comment: Simply: crazy code. Either use the builder pattern, or use a library like gson that turns json data into Java objects for you. Doing that manually, not a good idea!

Comment: @GhostCat thank you, ill take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling getDouble, you can use optDouble. The first value should be the key you're already using, the second value should be the value that will be used whenever the key is not found from the server response.

You can find some real world examples here: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.json.JSONObject&method=optDouble

Answer (score 0):

You should not use primitive variables. For example, int can't be null, On the other hand integer type can be null. Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26211744/java-null-in-constructor)

Comment: You should not give answers that are nothing more but comments.

Answer (score -1):

As GhostCat suggested, you should really consider builder pattern, example:

```
public Personnel {
    public static class Builder {
        int contactType;
        //all the other members

        public Builder contactType(int contactType) {
            this.contactType = contactType;
            return this;
        }

        public Personnel build() {
            Personnel personnel = new Personnel();
            personnel.contactType = this.contactType;
        }
    }


    int contactType;
    //all the other members

    private Personnel() {}

    // getters and setters

}

Personnel personnel = new Personnel.Builder()
    .contactType(0)
    .build();
```